# SQL Server 2014 Express refusing to install

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

This is a desperate cry for help. I am working on my finals exam and need a few tools to do this, mainly an SQL Server.

In short, I can't for whatever reason install SQL Server 2014 Express.
When installing, I just set up everything with its default values and settings and then let it perform the install, everything goes fine until it reaches the stage: **SqlEngineDbStartConfigaction_install_configrc_cpu64** where it stop with an error. Details can be seen in this picture as well as error code and description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFC5L.jpg

For the full error log just follow this link: http://pastebin.com/FfWeJi0i

I have tried literately everything I can think of, I edited permissions, registry, uninstalled reinstalled countless times, I updated windows several times, restarted countless times, I even went as far as to fully format my pc and start over.. however this too turned out to be a waste of time since the problem persists even after the reinstall of windows 7.
If I can't get this issue resolved I might not be able to finish my exam project, so consider me desperate.

Comment: Maybe you have done the following, but worth to double check: http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting160.htm, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451714/error-while-installing-sql-server-2012-standard-edition

Comment: First, why not try 2016?  There's nothing you can't do in 2016 that you can in 2014.  I recently had no end of troubles trying to install.  I deleted the key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0_Config and everything installed after that.  Risky, but you're desperate.

Comment: Because 2014 was the one provided by my education. Also I've already tried the deleting of reg keys associated to SQL Server Management.

Comment: @Prisoner I tried giving full access to the two registry keys in your first link, didnt make any change